# Wrong size when exporting SVG from Sketch

Tags: svg, sketch-3, sketchapp

When exporting an icon from Sketch as an SVG, it get exported with the wrong size.

The icon.svg file on the left is exported from Sketch.

But when I export the same file from Illustrator it exports it perfectly fine.

[image]

Here's my sketch export panel:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Sketch export the SVG with a height and width from your layout. 
As example 72x72 px and so you see the icon one the left site like this.

Solution:
Open the icon.svg with Dreamweaver > set height and width to "none" > save

It's not the best solution, but it works.